# hibernate subselect performance issue due to redundant load

Tags: hibernate

```
user(m:m)books

@Entity
public class User{
    @Id
    public int id;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Book.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_book", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"))
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    public List<Book> books;
}

@Entity
public class Book{
    @Id
    public int id;
    ...
}


loadAllActiveUsers()
foreach user
   do(user.books)
```

suppose that we have 1000 users which each of them have all books (we have 1000 books).
when call to user.books hibernate will trigger query:

```
select book.* from  association inner join books b on b.id = association.book_id where association.user_id in (select u.id from users u)
```

this query will has a result of 1M rows although we have 1000 books.
this is because hibernate load by the user_id and not by book_id.

If hibernate will do the join of the association in the where clause than the result will be limit to the distinct books and we will not query for duplicate books.

```
select book.* from books where b.id in (select association.book_id from users u join association a on a.user_id = u.id)
```

is there any way to tell hibernate to do the subselect in 2 steps : get the id of the associated and than get the associated entity?

Comment: Can you please post your entity mapping? I think the manytomany mapping is messed up.

Comment: I add a sample entities.